# Getting weird indent from style tags in html code

Tags: html, css, text, styles

I am a bit rusty with HTML and I have run into an issue with my styling code for a test site. I'm getting a really weird indent after a `<h4>` tag and I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm going to include the entire div and a screenshot to better troubleshoot this.

```
div style="color: #777;background-color:white; text-align: justify; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
<h1 style= "text-align: center;"> My Experience</h1>

        <span>
                <h4 style= "text-align: right;">April 2014- Present</h4>
                <h4>General Motors</h4>
                <h5>Senior Program Manager</h5>
                <p>

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        End to end responsibility for the success of
                        the critical global IT projects that will evolve and transform
                        GM’s business processes and capabilities. 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        Management of the IT project life cycle from definition to deployment,
                        through engagement with senior GM leaders, cross-functional stakeholders,
                        and development teams
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </p>

            <p>
            <h4 style= "text-align: right;">May 2012- March 2014</h4>
            <h4>Xtivia, INC</h4>
            <h5>PMO Manager</h5>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                    Provided direct leadership, organization and coordination to drive the delivery of complex portal implementations to customers in multiple sectors. 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    Guided project stakeholders in defining requirements, project scope and ensuring the effective utilization of team members. 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    Managed PMO’s functional activities, encompassing program planning, personnel management and product delivery.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </p>


        <h4 style = "float: left;">University of Nebrasksa - Omaha</h4><h4 style= "float: right;">June 2010 - Present</h4>
        </br>
        <h5>Adjunct Professor</h5>

        <p>
            Instructor for undergraduate Project Management and Cyber Ethics courses. 
        </p>
        <span><h4 style= "float: left;">Bellevue University</h4><h4 style= "float: right;">June 2010 - Present</h4></span>
        <br>
        <h5>Adjunct Professor</h5>

        <p>
            Instructor for graduate and undergraduate Computer Information Systems and Management Information Systems courses.
        </p>
    </span>
```

[image]

I'm sure it something simple but, like I said earlier, I'm rusty :)

Comment: Well, your code is semantically completely wrong (not that that has anything to do with the problem at hand, I'm just saying).

Comment: First: stop using inline styles, use a stylesheet to allow caching. Second, if you float something you take it out of the normal flow of the document which - sometimes - freaks out subsequent siblings. I'd guess that the `<h5>` could benefit from `clear: both`, perhaps. Incidentally, to elaborate on the previous comment: you're showing a list of things, use a list.

Comment: You should read up on semantics. Okay, quick recap: there is ONE `<h1>` on the page, of which everything else is a subsection. (Usually the `<h1>` is the page title/logo etc). Then comes `<h2>`, and then `<h3>` **within** the container with the `<h2>`. Headings are descendants, not used for how they normally look size-wise. Also, you have a weird use of `<span>` to contain some headings, and using floats, align right and such a bit haphazardly.

Comment: You have a bunch of HTML errors that mean your DOM probably doesn't look like you expect it to. Use a validator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Why exactly am I being marked down for asking a question?

Comment: @David Thomas Thank you for your input, the inline style tags are for ease of editing. Once i have it the way I want it Im moving it to css

Answer (score -1):

Here's a properly (mostly) version of your code

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  }
h2 span {
  float: right;
font-size: 0.75em;

}
#container {
  color: #777;
  text-align: justify; 
  margin: 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<h1>My Experience</h1>
  <h2>General Motors <span class="date">April 2014- Present</span></h2>
<h3>Senior Program Manager</h3>
<ul>
  <li>End to end responsibility for the success of
      the critical global IT projects that will evolve and transform
      GM’s business processes and capabilities. 
    </li>
    <li>
      Management of the IT project life cycle from definition to deployment,
      through engagement with senior GM leaders, cross-functional stakeholders,
      and development teams
    </li>
  </ul>

<h2>Xtivia, INC <span class="date">May 2012- March 2014</span></h2>
<h3>PMO Manager</h3>

<ul>
  <li>
    Provided direct leadership, organization and coordination to drive the delivery of complex portal implementations to customers in multiple sectors. 
  </li>
  <li>
    Guided project stakeholders in defining requirements, project scope and ensuring the effective utilization of team members. 
  </li>
  <li>
    Managed PMO’s functional activities, encompassing program planning, personnel management and product delivery.
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>University of Nebrasksa - Omaha <span class="date">June 2010 - Present</span></h2>
<h3>Adjunct Professor</h3>

<p>
  Instructor for undergraduate Project Management and Cyber Ethics courses. 
</p>
<h2>Bellevue University <span class="date">June 2010 - Present</span></h2>
<h3>Adjunct Professor</h3>

<p>
  Instructor for graduate and undergraduate Computer Information Systems and Management Information Systems courses.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense! Obviously i missed the mark semantically , this is the first time I'm trying this out with out something like Dreamweaver. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.